# Sand Castle Help File Builder - Organise by Assembly and not Namespaces

Tags: c#, documentation, shfb

SHFB is currently organizing my API reference documentation by namespaces as shown below:

[image]

However, I would prefer to organise my API reference documentation by assemblies/projects. `FinalEngine.Audio` and `FInalEngine.Audio.OpenAL` are in separate assemblies. Furthermore, `FinalEngine.Audio.OpenAL.Loaders` is in a sub-directory of the `FinalEngine.Audio.OpenAL` assembly/project.

Is this something that I can accomplish via SHFB?

- FinalEngine.Audio
- FinalEngine.Audio.OpenAL
- FinalEngine.Maths
- etc

Comment: AFAIK, SHFB uses compiled assemblies as its input. Therefore, it's impossible to know the directory structure of the original project in Visual Studio. So the answer to your second question regarding subdirectories is no. I don't know if SHFB is able to organize by assemblies. As a tip, VSdocman (I am the author) can accomplish this with custom topics and namespace placeholders. But it's not automatic, you need to set it manually. You need to realize, that readers of your API docs don't care about your project structure. The namespace structure is logical and it's used also by MS docs.